# Using TensorFlow with R: Getting error - attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, tensorflow

To use `TensorFlow` with R I followed the steps given here: https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow

As I try to run the following code:

```
sess = tf$Session()
hello <- tf$constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess$run(hello)
```

I get an error as shown below:

```
> sess = tf$Session()
Error: attempt to apply non-function
> hello <- tf$constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
Error: attempt to apply non-function
> sess$run(hello)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

What could be the reason for this? There were no errors while I installed TensorFlow for R

Comment: Not able to reproduce your error `sess$run(hello)#
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'`  When you did `install_tensorflow()` was there any errors?

Comment: @akrun No did not get any error. Had this warning though `==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.4.10
  latest version: 4.5.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda`

Comment: Then, you may need to update the conda as something functions may have changed

Comment: @akrun Same error

Comment: Did you test it from the python prompt first to make sure the core packages are installed Ok (before R)? Open python prompt, type: `import tensorflow as tf   //
 hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')  //
 sess = tf.Session()  //
 print(sess.run(hello))` (four lines of code)

Comment: @mysteRious Yeah. It works fine. Issue when working with R